# LDA VolumeViz details

Tags: format, visualization

I am looking for information about "LDA VolumeViz" (aka Amira Very Large Data File Formats). It is apparently being used in Amira, as can be seen [here](http://www.vsg3d.com/amira/very-large-data) on the very large data option page.

However a google search did not reveal any of the technological detail of the file format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LDA VolumeViz is an original file format created by [Mercury Systems](http://www.mrcy.com/) .

There is no open document with the schema file but you can get information from the [Open Inventor site](http://www.vsg3d.com/open-inventor/sdk) about [VolumeViz](http://www.vsg3d.com/open-inventor/volumeviz) and a bit explanation about the format from the Open Inventor Developer Zone, [What is VolumeViz](http://oivdoc93.vsg3d.com/content/111-what-volumeviz) and [LDM Data](http://oivdoc93.vsg3d.com/content/125-ldm-data)

All capters are part of the book [Open Inventor Mentor, 2nd Edition - Volume II](http://oivdoc93.vsg3d.com/content/open-inventor-mentor-2nd-edition-volume-ii)

I hope this helps you.